# Is there a way to store the last changes on real time database?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the real time database with the following data structure. I can add more machines in the webapp that attributes an autogenerated ID and all the machines has the same data structure.

```
machines
  -autogeneratedID1
    -id1 : 1
    -id2 : 2
  -autogeneratedID2
    -id1 : 4
    -Id2 : 3
```

I want to track the changes on the id inside the autogeneratedIDs, if the id1 on the autogeneratedID1 changes from 1 to 3, I want something that returns the change with a timestamp.

I'm trying to use cloud functions with the following code:

```
exports.foo = functions.database.ref("machines/").onUpdate((change) => {
    const before = change.before.val();  // DataSnapshot before the change
    const after = change.after.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change


    console.log(before);
    console.log(after);
    return null;
```

but the before and after objects returns me the JSON of all the strucutre of the database.
My first guess was to compare the 2 JSON objects and detect where the changes were and add a timestamp. Then I want to store the changes in the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer finally, here it is the code that I'm using:

```
exports.foo = functions.database.ref("machines/{machineID}/{ValueID}").onUpdate((change,context) => {
    const before = change.before.val();  // DataSnapshot before the change
    const after = change.after.val();    // DataSnapshot after the change

    const machineID = context.params.machineID; //Machine ID
    const valueID = context.params.ValueID;     //Value ID
    
    console.log("MachineID: " + machineID + " " +"IDChanged: " + valueID + " " + "BeforeValue: " + before +" "+ "AfterValue: " + after);


    return null;
});
```